# else if doesn't recognise a specific string

Tags: java, string, if-statement

I have come across this problem a few times, my code seems good but it just won't recognise a certain string. I use else if statements all the time but some of them just don't seem to work. I'm making a simple textbased game to excersise the things I have learned so far in java, which isn't that much. Please be gentle on my noobyness.
What am I doing wrong here, for some reason it doesn't recognise the command "herobrine" and just goes to the "else"?

User input: "enter"
output: "enter what"
user input: "herobrine"
output: "command not recognised"

```
public void scenetwo() {
System.out.println("You bump into herobrine, what do?");

Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
boolean ifone;
ifone = false;

String cmdone = in.next();
if (cmdone.equalsIgnoreCase("Help")) {
    Help helpObject = new Help();
    helpObject.Helpdisplay();

    Scenes ScenesObject = new Scenes();
    ScenesObject.scenetwo();
}
    else if (cmdone.equalsIgnoreCase("Enter")){
        System.out.println("Enter what?");  
        String conone = in.next();
        if (conone.equalsIgnoreCase("Forest")  || conone.equalsIgnoreCase("The forest")){
            System.out.println("You're already in the forest, dummy!");

            Scenes ScenesObject = new Scenes();
            ScenesObject.scenetwo();

        }
        else if (("Herobrine").equalsIgnoreCase(cmdone)) {
            System.out.println("You pervert, ok, you enter herobrine and his holyness digests you whole. Happy now?");


        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Command not recognised");
        }


    }
```

Comment: I see `conone` as your input and `cmdone` as the variable you are using for comparison. Is this the _exact_ code you are running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace `else if (("Herobrine").equalsIgnoreCase(cmdone))` by `else if (("Herobrine").equalsIgnoreCase(conone))`

Comment: Sorry that I wasted your time on a typo, I'm a bit tired you'll have to excuse me. Thank you though, was getting tunnelvision.

Comment: Still three minutes left :/ and can't up yet cuz I'm too low lvl :D

Answer (score 0):

If this is the exact code you are executing then look at the variable you use for the user's input and compare that to the variable you use inside the `else if`.
Change this line

```
else if (("Herobrine").equalsIgnoreCase(cmdone))
```

to

```
else if (("Herobrine").equalsIgnoreCase(conone)) // Using your input variable.
```

Answer (score 0):

You are evaluating the wrong variable. I assume you mean `conone` and not `cmdone`:

Here's your code, with the irrelevant parts for the answer snipped out, and some comment to explain:

```
if (cmdone.equalsIgnoreCase("Help")) {
    // snipped.
}
else if (cmdone.equalsIgnoreCase("Enter")){
    // If you entered here, you know the cmdone is "Enter" (in some case).

    System.out.println("Enter what?");  
    String conone = in.next();
    if (conone.equalsIgnoreCase("Forest")  || conone.equalsIgnoreCase("The forest")){
        // snipped
    }
    else if (("Herobrine").equalsIgnoreCase(cmdone)) {
        // cmdone can't be "herobrine" - it's known to be "enter".
        // you probably meant to check conone
    }
    else {
        // snipped
    }
}
```